# Wpf: Why does CaptureMouse() in OnMouseDown(...) raise OnMouseMove(...) event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Why does `CaptureMouse()` in `OnMouseDown(...)` raise `OnMouseMove(...)` event?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Trace.WriteLine( "OnMouseDown: Begin" );
        CaptureMouse();
        Trace.WriteLine( "OnMouseDown: End" );
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (IsMouseCaptured) Trace.WriteLine( "OnMouseMove" );
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Trace.WriteLine( "OnMouseUp" );
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
OnMouseDown: Begin
OnMouseMove // Wtf???
OnMouseDown: End
OnMouseMove
OnMouseMove
OnMouseMove
OnMouseUp
```

**Update**

`MouseDevice.Capture()` calls `MouseDevice.Synchronize()` which raises input event.

Answer (score 0):

If have recreated your situation, with just a regular WPF mainwindow.
Then I did as you did by overriding the `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseMove` and added `CaptureMouse()` to the `OnMouseDown` method.
Then I wrote to the console each time each method was invoked together with the milisecond value of the current datetime.
I got the following results:

`OnMouseMove |247
OnMouseMove |386
OnMouseMove |656
OnMouseDown |814
OnMouseDown |702
OnMouseDown |798
OnMouseDown |587
OnMouseDown |88
OnMouseMove |96
OnMouseMove |98
OnMouseMove |102`

You can see that I just moved my mouse, then clicked a few times and then moved my mouse again. This without causing `OnMouseMove` to be invoked when `OnMouseDown` was invoked.

Did you try to recreate your situation in a new clean WPF?

EDIT:

After updating the code, I ran into the same problem.
I don't have a solution / reason at the moment.

Comment: I have recreated you code and was able to reproduce the same problem. but I am not able to come up with an reason why / solution at the moment